# Retrieve Image from S3 with AWS lambda

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to retrieve images from `Amazon S3` for my React project. However, my react project setup seems to contradict with aws-sdk which can be traced back to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296569/how-to-retrieve-image-from-s3-with-nodejs).

Therefore, I am trying to have `AWS lambda` as my MiddleWare to retrieve the Image. I utilised `s3.getSignedUrlPromise()` to get a signed url of the image, then pass the url back to the frontend. In the local environment, this approach works and I can render the requested image with the signed url retrieved from backend.

However, when I deployed the lambda function, the signed url reads `403 forbidden` file. Hence I believe that the signed url is bound to the domain which is `localhost`. The question is, is there a way to tell `getSingedUrlPromise()` which host is the signed url supposed to be bound to?

I also attempted to use `s3.getObject()` api but I had a very hard time trying to convert the Buffer object to Image.

Comment: which version of the aws-sdk are you using ?

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869962/getting-403-forbidden-when-uploading-to-s3-with-a-signed-url)? I've resolved same situation referring to that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `@aws-sdk/client-s3`,  I had implemented a similar example to fetch image from my `S3 bucket` using the below code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
//*/ get reference to S3 client 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
      "Bucket": "your-bucket-name",
      "Key": "your-key"
    };
    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data){
       if(err) {
           callback(err, null);
       } else {
           let base64String= data.Body.toString('base64');
           let src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+base64String;
           
           let response = {
             "statusCode": 200,
             "base64image": base64String
           };

           callback(null, response);
       }
    });
    
};
```